# Using Laravel View Composer to format page titles

Tags: php, laravel, view, laravel-blade

I am trying to use a View composer to automatically modify page titles based on a defined section.

```
@section('title', 'Page')
```

And use it like this:

```
<title>{{ $title }}</title>
```

I've written the following code as the composer, but it doesn't work correctly. It just displays the title as `Website - Website` when it should say `Page - Website` or, in the case of not including a title, `Website`.

```
View::composer('*', function($view){
    $title = $view->title;
    $view->with('title', !empty($title) ? $title . " - Website" : "Website");
});
```

This only needs to work on one template, `master`, but when I replaced `'*'` with `'master'` it didn't modify the behaviour at all.

What do I need to change to make this correctly modify the `title` section?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
view()->composer('*', function ($view) {
         $view->with('title', 'Your title');
});
```

In  service provider.
Or you can use share

```
view()->share('key', 'value');
```

Then in view use

> {{ $key }}

May be try to use this:

```
 view()->composer('*', function ($view) {
                   $data = $view->getData();
                   //here you can get your data which was sent to view
                   //exmp. $old_title = $data['title']; 
                   //where 'title' - key of variable which sent via ->with('title','data')   
                   $view->with('title', 'new title');
});
```

Comment: The problem is I'm trying to access an existing variable set as a section.

Comment: Now it says `Undefined index: title`, I'm not sure why.

Comment: @Furze did you sent your title to view? In your controller. And where it says `undefined index`

Comment: I've done that, and now it's working. Is there any way to get it to work from a section variable? Like `@section('title', 'My Title')`?

Comment: @Furze I don't know how it possible to do.